# Innodb log flush to prevent data loss

Tags: mysql, logging, innodb, flush, fault-tolerance

I need to have a high power fault tollerance to my innodb engine and i can not change hardware configuration. 
Do you suggest to call

```
FLUSH ENGINE LOGS;
```

after a very important operations?
Can it help to prevent data loss from poweroff or process crash?

Answer (score 1):

Using `FLUSH ENGINE LOGS` should be unnecessary. Your configuration of MySQL/InnoDB should have:

- `innodb_flush_logs_at_trx_commit = 1`
- `sync_binlog = 1`

Beyond that, if your hardware is not reliable, there's not much that can be done.

Comment: The default "server machine" configuraton type doesn't have "sync_binlog" enabled do you suggest to enable it? Sometimes after a power fault I found many data loss, not just data from last server startup but from 3-4 startup before... do you think this can be avoid with this option?

Comment: No. The `sync_binlog` flag only controls whether binary logs are flushed to disk. Binary logs are used for replication, so they help  replication not be completely broken by a crash. If you're seeing data loss up to 3-4 restarts prior, that would imply that data is never synced to disk, and I would be looking for a new host, personally.

Comment: I can't :-) this is a client application and sometimes I can not choose hardware... Can you suppose causes of this sync lack? I'm sure this happends after some power fault, but I can not understand why. I can accept a data loss from last transactions, but why from many days before?

Comment: You'd have to specify what hardware and OS configuration you're running on. This could only really happen because data is not being flushed to disk as it should be, somewhere in the stack.

Comment: I also wrote a topic here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,604726,604726 but without much luck... I found this problem in two different Win7 computer that suffered of some power faults (standard computer, no raid or particular hdd). Mysql truncated some data without any particular notice in logs, I thought that was a rare case, but I found the same problem after few months in another computer with the same power-off history.